# How to change the name of a Django app?

Tags: python, django

I have changed the name of an app in Django by renaming its folder, imports and all its references (templates/indexes). But now I get this error when I try to run `python manage.py runserver`

```
Error: Could not import settings 'nameofmynewapp.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named settings
```

How can I debug and solve this error? Any clues?

Comment: Hi danihp. Yes I have. I'm also using virtualenv, I don't know If that have something to do with.

Comment: If, by any chance, you are using PyCharm, its `rename` feature will greatly help you with this.

Comment: Isn't South suporting such operation?

Comment: @andi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566978/renaming-an-app-with-django-and-south

Answer (score 418, accepted):

Follow these steps to change an app's name in Django:

1. Rename the folder which is in your project root
2. Change any references to your app in their dependencies, i.e. the app's `views.py`, `urls.py` , `manage.py` , and `settings.py` files.
3. Edit the database table `django_content_type` with the following command: `UPDATE django_content_type SET app_label='<NewAppName>' WHERE app_label='<OldAppName>'`
4. Also, if you have models, you will have to rename the model tables. For postgres, use `ALTER TABLE <oldAppName>_modelName RENAME TO <newAppName>_modelName`. For mysql too, I think it is the same (as mentioned by @null_radix).
5. (For Django >= 1.7) Update the `django_migrations` table to avoid having your previous migrations re-run: `UPDATE django_migrations SET app='<NewAppName>' WHERE app='<OldAppName>'`. **Note**: there is some debate (in comments) if this step is required for Django 1.8+; If someone knows for sure please update here.
6. If your `models.py` 's Meta Class has `app_name` listed, make sure to rename that too (mentioned by @will).
7. If you've namespaced your `static` or `templates` folders inside your app, you'll also need to rename those. For example, rename `old_app/static/old_app` to `new_app/static/new_app`.
8. For renaming django `models`, you'll need to change `django_content_type.name` entry in DB. For postgreSQL, use `UPDATE django_content_type SET name='<newModelName>' where name='<oldModelName>' AND app_label='<OldAppName>'`
9. **Update 16Jul2021**: Also, the `__pycache__/` folder inside the app must be removed, otherwise you get `EOFError: marshal data too short when trying to run the server`. Mentioned by @Serhii Kushchenko
10. Update the apps.py file in the app you're renaming to use the new name. Change the "<old_app_name>Config" class name to "<new_app_name>Config" and within this class change name = '<old_app_name>' to name = '<new_app_name>'

**Meta point (If using virtualenv):** Worth noting, if you are renaming the directory that contains your virtualenv, there will likely be several files in your env that contain an absolute path and will also need to be updated. If you are getting errors such as `ImportError: No module named ...` this might be the culprit. (thanks to @danyamachine for providing this).

**Other references:** you might also want to refer to the below links for a more complete picture:

1. [Renaming an app with Django and South](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566978/renaming-an-app-with-django-and-south)
2. [How do I migrate a model out of one django app and into a new one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258130/how-do-i-migrate-a-model-out-of-one-django-app-and-into-a-new-one)
3. [How to change the name of a Django app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408046/how-to-change-the-name-of-a-django-app?noredirect=1&lq=1)
4. [Backwards migration with Django South](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814190/backwards-migration-with-django-south?rq=1)
5. [Easiest way to rename a model using Django/South?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862979/easiest-way-to-rename-a-model-using-django-south?rq=1)
6. [Python code](https://github.com/amirraouf/change-django-app-name) (thanks to [A.Raouf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1690893/a-raouf)) to automate the above steps (Untested code. You have been warned!)
7. [Python code](https://gist.github.com/rafaponieman/201054ddf725cda1e60be3fe845850a5) (thanks to [rafaponieman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2453104/rafaponieman)) to automate the above steps (Untested code. You have been warned!)

Comment: Hi, this error was caused by having the name of the app with the same name of the project... Thanks for the help.

Comment: Also if you have models, you will have to rename the model tables. For postgres use  `ALTER TABLE <oldAppName>_modelName RENAME TO <newAppName>_modelName`

Comment: how to change the name of tableName_id_seq ?

Comment: So the **name** column corresponds to the name of the model and the **app_label** corresponds to the name of the app? What about the last column, **model**?

Comment: If using fixtures, do a find and replace on oldAppName. to newAppName. within the fixtures.

Comment: If your Models.py's Meta Class has 'app_name' listed, make sure to rename that too

Comment: And if you're using the new migrations, you'll need to change the app name in the existing migrations files and django_migrations table.  It might be better to squash migrations first so there's less to edit.

Comment: For Postgres, If you want to rename the sequence too, then use `ALTER SEQUENCE <oldAppName>_<modelName>_<PK>_seq RENAME TO <newAppName>_<modelName>_<PK>_seq;`. Although it is not necessary, the system itself doesn't care about the name. The column DEFAULT stores an `OID` (`'foo_pkey_seq'::regclass`), you can change the name of the sequence without breaking that - the OID stays the same.

Comment: Is there an equivalent of this with Homebrew for Mac? I keep getting in my terminal: "UPDATE command not found".

Comment: Would be great if you updated your answer to include what James said about upgrading migration **files** (such as dependency module names)... couldn't figure that out for quite a bit.

Comment: Regarding #5, the renaming of models:  I think you mean `model` instead of `name`.  There isn't a `name` column on that table (I'm on Django 1.8), just [`id`, `app_label`, and `model`].

Comment: @TheGrimmScientist for us users for Django 1.8+ I think we have to skip step 5 right?

Comment: worth noting, if you are renaming the directory that contains your virtualenv: there will likely be several files in your env that contain an absolute path and will also need to be updated. If you are getting errors such as `ImportError: No module named ...` this might be the culprit.

Comment: I tried to implement your answer here
https://github.com/amirraouf/change-django-app-name

Comment: Here's a management command that allows for model renaming according to @SrikarAppalaraju's solution:

https://gist.github.com/rafaponieman/201054ddf725cda1e60be3fe845850a5

It accepts old_name, new_name and classes as parameters (all formatted as they look on the database tables and fields).

Comment: And how can we deal with the migrations?

Comment: Any reason not to use the ORM to rename `ContentType` and `Migrations` models?

Comment: The approach in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45007732/875379 seems to work much simpler.

Comment: As a final step I had to remove and remake the migrations (django `2.1.1`)

Comment: You can also run `manage.py migrate --fake <new-app>` one time after you rename. That way your history for migrations shows the old app migrations as well as the new.

Comment: I'm on `Django 2.2` and for step 8, I am not seeing that the table `django_content_type` has a column called `name`. The only columns I see are `id`, `app_label`, and `model`.

Comment: @chefarov To preserve migration history, I ran all my migrations files through `sed`, changing all references to the app name.

Comment: @SrikarAppalaraju what happens to the foreignkey constraints ? It seems changing them is not mentioned here. One of my foreignkey constraint reads like this "articles_article_author_id_16bbf05c_fk_account_account_id" FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES account_account(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED

here account is my app name.

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal I have not tried this but i guess you can first alter the underlying database (of any foreign key changes) and then modify the django `models.py` file of the said changes.

Comment: What is `django_content_type` used for? I know the comment asks to make changes to that table, I want to understand what it does? @SrikarAppalaraju

Comment: This is really cumbersome :( is there a way to automate all that? for example in the `manage.py` file to have a script right before the `execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)` line?

Comment: @Foad Some folks seems to have automated this. See of [this](https://github.com/amirraouf/change-django-app-name) or [this](https://gist.github.com/rafaponieman/201054ddf725cda1e60be3fe845850a5) helps you.

Comment: If you're using `Pycharm Professional`, simply "refactor and rename" by selecting the app folder and pressing `shift + F6`. The IDE will list all the usages for you. If you're in development stage, simply rerun migrations, and you're good. :)

Comment: I'm coming from laravel and this is seriously messed up how much we have to go through to rename an app.

Comment: So what should I do with the virtualenv import errors then?!

Comment: Also, the __pycache__/ folder inside the app must be removed, otherwise you get EOFError: marshal data too short when trying to run the server

Comment: One good option to keep your existing tables is to use Meta "db_table". Find the existing name and use it as value of `db_table` so you don't need to rename / modify DB. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#db-table

Comment: @KonstantineKalbazov an we also rename indexes and foreign keys like that?

Answer (score 42):

New in Django 1.7 is a app registry that stores configuration and provides introspection. This machinery let's you change several app attributes.

The main point I want to make is that renaming an app isn't always necessary: With app configuration it is possible to resolve conflicting apps. But also the way to go if your app needs friendly naming.

As an example I want to name my polls app 'Feedback from users'. It goes like this:

Create a `apps.py` file in the `polls` directory:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class PollsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'polls'
    verbose_name = "Feedback from users"
```

Add the default app config to your `polls/__init__.py`:

```
default_app_config = 'polls.apps.PollsConfig'
```

For more app configuration: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/applications/

Answer (score 22):

Fun problem! I'm going to have to rename a lot of apps soon, so I did a dry run.

This method allows progress to be made in atomic steps, to minimise disruption for other developers working on the app you're renaming.

*See the link at the bottom of this answer for working example code.*

1. **Prepare existing code for the move**:

   - Create an [app config](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/) (set `name` and `label` to defaults).
   - Add the app config to `INSTALLED_APPS`.
   - On all models, explicitly set `db_table` to the current value.
   - Doctor migrations so that `db_table` was "always" explicitly defined.
   - Ensure no migrations are required (checks previous step).
2. **Change the app label**:

   - Set `label` in app config to new app name.
   - Update migrations and foreign keys to reference new app label.
   - Update templates for generic class-based views (the [default path is `<app_label>/<model_name>_<suffix>.html`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView.template_name_suffix))
   - Run raw SQL to fix migrations and `content_types` app (unfortunately, some raw SQL is unavoidable). **You can not run this in a migration.**

     ```
     UPDATE django_migrations
        SET app = 'catalogue'
      WHERE app = 'shop';

     UPDATE django_content_type
        SET app_label = 'catalogue'
      WHERE app_label = 'shop';
     ```
   - Ensure no migrations are required (checks previous step).
3. **Rename the tables**:

   - Remove "custom" `db_table`.
   - Run `makemigrations` so django can rename the table "to the default".
4. **Move the files**:

   - Rename module directory.
   - Fix imports.
   - Update app config's `name`.
   - Update where `INSTALLED_APPS` references the app config.
5. **Tidy up**:

   - Remove custom app config if it's no longer required.
   - If app config gone, don't forget to also remove it from `INSTALLED_APPS`.

---

**Example solution:** I've created [app-rename-example](https://github.com/meshy/app-rename-example), an example project where you can see how I renamed an app, one commit at a time.

The example uses Python 2.7 and Django 1.8, but I'm confident the same process will work on at least Python 3.6 and Django 2.1.

Comment: Thanks @meshy. It really helped me to rename a huge app. One suggestion, after running the last migration you could delete all the migration files and recreate the initial migration file which would help you if you are doing any continuous integration testing otherwise the CI will fail to create the test database.

Comment: I had written this in the expectation of migrations being runnable from scratch once the process was finished. If the migrations failed, perhaps one of us missed something. I'll have a think about it, and see if there are any other steps I need to add.

Comment: @Rohan is there any information you could provide to detail exactly how the migrations failed?

Comment: If you run test locally with the old migration files you can see it will fail to create the tables @meshy

Comment: After completing all the steps there is no need of keeping the old migrations file because the database is now have different tables names. So, you could add one more additional step of deleting all the migrations files and rerunning the `makemigrations` command to generate the fresh migration file which will be consistent with the database tables. @meshy. But still you did a great job to tackle this issue. Thank you for that.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad it's' been useful to you :) Thank you for the extra information. For my use-case, it's going to be important to keep the migrations, so I'll come back to this at some point, and try to fix that particular issue.

Comment: This game plan worked perfectly for me. So long as each step is deployed through all active checkouts (CI, other devs, production, etc) before the next step is tackled, it worked perfectly -- no problems with the existing historical migrations.  Do the steps in order, and propagate the changes everywhere before moving to the following step.

Comment: Thank you for this guide! I can confirm that this still works with Python 3.10 and Django 4.1. PS: Steps 3 and 4 are interchangeable.

Answer (score 15):

In many cases, I believe @allcaps's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27225328) works well.

However, sometimes it is necessary to actually rename an app, e.g. to improve code readability or prevent confusion.

Most of the other answers involve either [manual database manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8408131) or [tinkering with existing migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51581569), which I do not like very much.

As an alternative, I like to create a new app with the desired name, copy everything over, make sure it works, then remove the original app:

1. Start a *new* app with the desired name, and copy all code from the original app into that. Make sure you fix the namespaced stuff, in the newly copied code, to match the new app name.
2. `makemigrations` and `migrate`. Note: if the app has a lot of foreign keys, there will likely be issues with clashing reverse accessors when trying to run the initial migration for the copied app. You have to rename the related_name accessor (or add new ones) on the old app to resolve the clashes.
3. Create a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) that copies the relevant data from the original app's tables into the new app's tables, and `migrate` again.

At this point, everything still works, because the original app and its data are still in place.

4. Now you can refactor all the dependent code, so it only makes use of the new app. See other answers for examples of what to look out for.
5. Once you are certain that everything works, you can remove the original app. This involves another (schema) migration.

This has the advantage that every step uses the normal Django migration mechanism, without manual database manipulation, and we can track everything in source control. In addition, we keep the original app and its data in place until we are sure everything works.

Comment: Though guessing this would cause problems if you wanted to run the migrations on a fresh installation after deleting the origianal app, right? Cause the data migrations would point to a now non-existing app.

Comment: @OzgurAkcali: I think a fresh installation should not be a problem, because data migrations specify dependencies, just like any other migration, and they (should) use historical models. The data migration will not do anything, as there are no data to migrate. However, in case of a *completely fresh* installation, I would start with a clean slate, so either delete all migrations and create new ones, or squash all of them.

Comment: Hmm, yeah they should be using historical models. Was wondering if a line like this would caise a problem: apps.get_model('old_app', 'ModelName') when old app was deleted. If that would be safe, thne I guess running step 3 after step 5 would also be safe.

Comment: @OzgurAkcali: I don't think `apps.get_model()` will cause a problem when the old app is deleted. On the contrary, this is what it is for: `apps.get_model()` returns a "pseudo-"model, built from the migration history. At that point in the migration history, the app still exists. See docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/#historical-models) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/#data-migrations).

Comment: @OzgurAkcali: Although I did not mention it explicitly, step 5 ("remove the original app"), also involves a schema migration. I've edited the answer to clarify. So, no, step 3 cannot be done after that.

Comment: This seems like a much cleaner approach than the other methods mentioned here.

Answer (score 14):

In case you are using PyCharm and project stops working after rename:

1. Edit Run/Debug configuration and change environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE, since it includes your project name.
2. Go to Settings / Languages & Frameworks / Django and update the settings file location.

Comment: This is one of those situations where find and replace failed me. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 4):

Re-migrate approach for a cleaner plate.

This can painlessly be done IF other apps do not foreign key models from the app to be renamed. Check and make sure their migration files don't list any migrations from this one.

1. Backup your database. Dump all tables with a) data + schema for possible circular dependencies, and b) just data for reloading.
2. Run your tests.
3. Check all code into VCS.
4. Delete the database tables of the app to be renamed.
5. Delete the permissions: `delete from auth_permission where content_type_id in (select id from django_content_type where app_label = '<OldAppName>')`
6. Delete content types: `delete from django_content_type where app_label = '<OldAppName>'`
7. Rename the folder of the app.
8. Change any references to your app in their dependencies, i.e. the app's `views.py`, `urls.py` , 'manage.py' , and `settings.py` files.
9. Delete migrations: `delete from django_migrations where app = '<OldAppName>'`
10. If your `models.py` 's Meta Class has `app_name` listed, make sure to rename that too (mentioned by @will).
11. If you've namespaced your `static` or `templates` folders inside your app, you'll also need to rename those. For example, rename `old_app/static/old_app` to `new_app/static/new_app`.
12. If you defined app config in apps.py; rename those, and rename their references in settings.INSTALLED_APPS
13. Delete migration files.
14. Re-make migrations, and migrate.
15. Load your table data from backups.

Answer (score 3):

Simple 4 steps to rename an existing app in Django project without any pain or data loss.

**Step 1**

Rename the app folder. For this example,"old_app" is our old name and "new_app" is our new name".

`mv ./old_app ./new_app`

**Step 2**

Update all imports referencing the old folder to reference the new.

For example:

```
# Before 
from myproject.old_app import models

# After
from myproject.new_app import models
```

**Step 3**

Update old app name references within the [Django migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/).

Example changes you'll likely have to make:

```
# Before

dependencies = [
    ('old_app', '0023_auto_20200403_1050'),
]

# After

dependencies = [
    ('new_app', '0023_auto_20200403_1050'),
]

# Before

field = models.ForeignKey(
    default=None, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE,
    to='old_app.Experiment'
)

# After

field = models.ForeignKey(
    default=None, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE,
    to='new_app.Experiment'
)
```

**Step 4**

Make a commit at this point.

Then, however you run your application migrations in a deployed environment, run [django_rename_app](https://github.com/odwyersoftware/django-rename-app) before you run your migrations in that process.

i.e Before "python manage.py migrate --noinput", as the example below shows.

```
# Before

python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
python manage.py migrate --noinput
gunicorn my_project.wsgi:application

# After

python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
python manage.py rename_app old_app new_app
python manage.py migrate --noinput
gunicorn my_project.wsgi:application
```

This will update the app name in the following internal Django database tables:

- django_content_type
- django_migrations

And rename the prefix of all of your tables to start with your new app name, rather than the old one.

That's it.

**Note :** Its better to use your IDE's/text editor's **find & replace** function for making changes in the various files.

Answer (score 1):

If you use **Pycharm**, renaming an app is very easy with **refactoring**(`Shift`+`F6` default) for all project files.
But make sure you delete the `__pycache__` folders in the project directory & its sub-directories. Also be careful as it also renames comments too which you can exclude in the refactor preview window it will show you.
And you'll have to rename OldNameConfig(AppConfig): in `apps.py` of your renamed app in addition.

If you do not want to lose data of your database, you'll have to manually do it with query in database like the aforementioned answer.

Comment: also worth noting, if you're still having issues when using pycharm delete the .idea folder, then re-open the project in pycharm

Answer (score 1):

My simple alternative that avoids manual database manipulation (similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/64133141/1608851), works well in a CI/CD, and is reversible.

1. Create an empty migration in the "old" app that renames the tables, content type, and migration records. Include a reverse migration.
   Example:

```
from django.db import migrations

sql = """
ALTER TABLE oldapp_examplemodel RENAME TO newapp_examplemodel;
UPDATE django_migrations SET app ='newapp' WHERE app ='oldapp';
UPDATE django_content_type SET app_label ='newapp' WHERE app_label ='oldapp';
"""

reverse_sql = """
ALTER TABLE newapp_examplemodel RENAME TO oldapp_examplemodel;
UPDATE django_migrations SET app ='oldapp' WHERE app ='newapp';
UPDATE django_content_type SET app_label ='oldapp' WHERE app_label ='newapp';
"""


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('oldapp', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL(sql, reverse_sql)
    ]
```

2. Set the model table name to the new_app.
   Example:

```
class ExampleModel(models.Model):

    # normal column definitions...

    class Meta:
        db_table = "newapp_examplemodel"  # add this line to the meta class
```

3. Commit, test, and deploy the above changes.
4. Delete the migration created in step 1.
5. Rename/move the old app and fix all references (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8408131/1608851 for more details), including references in migrations.
6. Remove the `db_table` overrides from the model meta classes.
7. Commit, test, and deploy.

Notes:

- The `django_migrations` table will retain a row with the old app, because that row is added *after* our new migration was run, but before it was registered under the new app name. It should be okay to leave that as is.
- Deleting the migration is due to the above point, but also to prevent future issues when reverse migrating, but also because
- Reversing this app rename requires checking out / deploying the commit from step 3, then reversing our migration, then checking out / deploying the commit before that

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the [django-rename-app](https://github.com/odwyersoftware/django-rename-app%20tool) tool.

1. Install the [django-rename-app](https://pypi.org/project/django-rename-app/) package
2. Add it to the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting
3. Rename your app folder to the new name
4. Perform a find and replace to rename all occurences of the old name
   in your repository ([in vscode for instance](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_search-and-replace))
5. Commit the changes
6. Run the tool: `python manage.py rename_app old_app new_app`

For more detailled intstructions, visit:

- https://github.com/odwyersoftware/django-rename-app
- https://pypi.org/project/django-rename-app
- https://odwyer.software/blog/how-to-rename-an-existing-django-application

Answer (score 0):

Instead can we do this way ?

Create New app with NewName
Move all the models, view,
Change appropriately names inside the app in your imports
abandone the old app.

Just a thought.

Answer (score -5):

Why not just use the option Find and Replace. (every code editor has it)?

For example Visual Studio Code (under Edit option):

[image: Visual Studio Code option: 'Replace in files']

You just type in old name and new name and replace everyhting in the project with one click.

**NOTE**: This renames only file content, NOT file and folder names. Do not forget renaming folders, eg. `templates/my_app_name/` rename it to `templates/my_app_new_name/`