# How to use Django packages with the same name?

Tags: django

There are two Django packages with the same option that I must add to the settings:

> Add "captcha" to the INSTALLED_APPS in your settings.py

But it is not possible to add `"captcha"`to the settings two times because I will get the next error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: captcha

So how can I use two packages with the same name in my Django project?

*PS: Please do not confuse "packages" and Django "apps". It described in official documentation about using apps with the same name, but there is nothing about packages.*

Comment: packages contain app

Comment: Why do you need two packages that provide a captcha app?

Comment: @shafik maybe I do not understand some things in Python/Django yet. If you have something to point me to a solution, please describe detailed.

Comment: @DanielRoseman one package for Google ReCaptcha and another - for custom captchas. But this is off-topic. I hope to solve this Django packages problem.

Comment: You have to set a unique name for your custom captcha app because Django expects all app has a unique name.

Answer (score 0):

You might Google "django rename app" and find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53025021/5246906)

I did once successfully rename an app following it and then fixing up problems, but it's also a definite case of "here be dragons". Nevertheless, if you back up so you can revert if it all goes wrong, and especially if one or other app does **not** haver any database tables or migrations, then you might succeed. The dragons are the details ... only way to find out is to try it, see what breaks, try to fix the breakages ....