# Copied and modified Django project stills show old templates

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, duplicates

I copied and pasted [a project developed with Django](https://github.com/antoinecomp/todowoo) to modify it. However, after modifying one of the templates a little (the home.html), no modification appears. Is it because this project is not original? Do I have to recreate it from the beginning?

For example, I changed the name of the template "home.html" to "homes.html". Then the first one should not be called and all that should result in an error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

But as you can see there is no error and the home.html continues to be called

Even after following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58413290/4764604) about renaming a Django project, I can't see my modifications being taken into account.

Comment: Did you restart the server? Depending on the settings, templates might be cached.

Comment: @schwobaseggl CTRL+C and restart? Yes :'(

Comment: Stupid question :) Are you in the correct project? `todowoo.settings` looks suspicious.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I think you're right ! I'm going to close my question, downvote me and rename my pseudo as `stoop_id`. I am now probably facing common issues of copied/paste/modified django project ... I might be here again with new questions