# django - migrations issue after renaming app

Tags: django, django-models

I renamed some django app , and now want to run `migrate` to update the database. But I get the following error because the old names still are still referenced in the migrations files.

> ValueError: Lookup failed for model referenced by field pr1.Ticket.project: prod.Project

I already tried `./manage.py flush` to reset the database, but that doesn't seem to help.
What is the correct way to 'reset' or initialize the migrations?

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408046/how-to-change-the-name-of-a-django-app ?

Comment: @Bilou06 something similar. However, not the sql command, because I simply `flush`ed the database. Renaming everything went fine. only place where the old name still exists is in the migrations files.

Comment: The part "5. (For Django >= 1.7) Update the django_migrations table to avoid having your previous migrations re-run: UPDATE django_migrations SET app='<NewAppName>' WHERE app='<OldAppName>'" doesn't do it ?

Comment: If you were ready to flush the db, you might as well delete the db file and run makemigrations

Comment: migrate or makemigrations is what gives the error. (I'm using mysql, not sqlite.)

Comment: After you drop your database you need to remove and recreate your migrations for this app too. Try with this app only but you may run into errors when another app depends on renamed one in its migrations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about your migrations, and the data, just delete the content of the migrations folder and create them again:

```
rm -f yourapp/migrations/*
touch yourapp/migrations/__init__.py
./manage.py makemigrations
```