# django, can I rename the application without breaking references?

Tags: django

I have a django directory named application.

I want to change it's name to something else. 
However all the code references to the application namespace:

```
from application.xxx import *
```

What is the proper way to change the application name without breaking all the references?

Comment: A popular search engine suggests this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408046/how-to-change-the-name-of-a-django-app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the name of a Django app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408046/how-to-change-the-name-of-a-django-app)

Comment: Somewhat unrelated but you should NEVER use star imports ("from xxx import *") in modules code - it makes it very difficult to track dependencies (where does each name comes from) and can easily lead to names being overwritten.

Comment: To answer the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408046/how-to-change-the-name-of-a-django-app mostly sum it up. You will OF COURSE have to find and replace all references to your app name throughout the whole project.