# Django 1.8 raises error "module X has no attribute 'run'" after upgrading to Python 3.5

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-3.5

I have a Django project running under Django 1.8.4 that I'm trying to upgrade to latest version of Django.  Since I was still using Python 2.7 on a Debian 8 server, I first upgraded my server to Debian 9 and then I upgraded my Django project's virtual environment to Python 3.5.3 (the default version of Python 3 on Debian 9).

After I rebuilt the virtual environment to use Python 3, I ran the command `2to3 -w .` in my project's root folder.  `2to3` found and fixed 62 problems without any difficulties.  I also have 216 unit tests and only two of them failed under Python 3.5.

I then went to my Django website and the site appeared to be working except that the forms that contain pull-down elements show "SomeThingobject" instead of the values from the SomeThing table.  I ran a few SQL queries directly against the database and confirmed that my SomeThing lookup table is populated.

Now I want to run a Django queryset command in the Python shell like the following to see why my pulldowns are not showing my column values:

```
    queryset=SomeThing.objects.all()
```

However, if I activate my virtual environment and try to run the command `./manage.py shell`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/srv/https/my_project.com/venvs/0bc664fa2a7b562d0b7e42a7acb3f095fe5df3cf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/srv/https/my_project.com/venvs/0bc664fa2a7b562d0b7e42a7acb3f095fe5df3cf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/srv/https/my_project.com/venvs/0bc664fa2a7b562d0b7e42a7acb3f095fe5df3cf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/srv/https/my_project.com/venvs/0bc664fa2a7b562d0b7e42a7acb3f095fe5df3cf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/srv/https/my_project.com/venvs/0bc664fa2a7b562d0b7e42a7acb3f095fe5df3cf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 69, in handle
    self.run_shell(shell=options['interface'])
  File "/srv/https/my_project.com/venvs/0bc664fa2a7b562d0b7e42a7acb3f095fe5df3cf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 58, in run_shell
    return getattr(self, shell)()
  File "/srv/https/my_project.com/venvs/0bc664fa2a7b562d0b7e42a7acb3f095fe5df3cf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 41, in ipython
    ip()
  File "/srv/https/my_project.com/venvs/0bc664fa2a7b562d0b7e42a7acb3f095fe5df3cf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 34, in _ipython
    from IPython import start_ipython
  File "/srv/https/my_project.com/venvs/0bc664fa2a7b562d0b7e42a7acb3f095fe5df3cf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "/srv/https/my_project.com/venvs/0bc664fa2a7b562d0b7e42a7acb3f095fe5df3cf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/terminal/embed.py", line 19, in <module>
    from IPython.terminal.ipapp import load_default_config
  File "/srv/https/my_project.com/venvs/0bc664fa2a7b562d0b7e42a7acb3f095fe5df3cf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 30, in <module>
    from IPython.core.magics import ScriptMagics
  File "/srv/https/my_project.com/venvs/0bc664fa2a7b562d0b7e42a7acb3f095fe5df3cf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .execution import ExecutionMagics
  File "/srv/https/my_project.com/venvs/0bc664fa2a7b562d0b7e42a7acb3f095fe5df3cf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.py", line 21, in <module>
    import cProfile as profile
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/cProfile.py", line 22, in <module>
    run.__doc__ = _pyprofile.run.__doc__
AttributeError: module 'profile' has no attribute 'run'
```

Now I do have an application named 'profile' in my INSTALLED_APPS.  If I try to open the Python shell on my production server which is still using Python 2.7, the shell executes without a problem.  It's only having this problem with Python 3.5.  What's interesting is that my Django 1.8/Python 2.7 project contains `.pyc` files but now under Python 3, they're replaced with `__pycache__/<filename>.cpython-35.pyc` files.

I read the Django document [Porting to Python 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/python3/) but it doesn't seem to allude to this problem.  What do I have to do to make this Django project operate properly under Python 3.5?  Is there perhaps something new in Python 3.5 that is having a conflict with my `profile` application or is it something else?

Answer (score 1):

After much digging around in the Python code I surmised that the problem was being caused by the fact that one of my applications inside the Django project was called "profile" and this was conflicting with a profile module in the newer version of cPython in Python 3.5.  After I changed the name of the application to "userprofile" I could start the shell without any problems.  These two articles help me change the app's name:

Stackoverflow: [How to change the name of a Django app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408046/how-to-change-the-name-of-a-django-app)

[How to Change Name of Django Application](https://coderbook.com/@marcus/how-to-change-name-of-django-application/)