# what are the issues if I change django app name?

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-apps

I know there are questions regarding **how to change django app name** but none of them talk about what are the downstream effects of changing the name of django app.
Is it possible to keep the old table and migration names ?

Comment: This question is answered step by step [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408046/how-to-change-the-name-of-a-django-app)

Answer (score 0):

Already discussed in this post:
[How to change the name of a Django app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408046/how-to-change-the-name-of-a-django-app)

Srikar Appalaraju did there a nice job by for your question.