# Django (find & replace all) - Choices are: 'Config'. django.core....ImproperlyConfigured: 'adolim.apps' does not contain a class 'AdolimConfig'

Tags: django

I messed something up: I performed **find & replace all** in PyCharm for the name of my app:

From 'adolim' to 'adulim - by mistake I clicked and changed the configuration files too.

Now when I want to run **anything** I'm getting: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'adolim.apps' does not contain a class 'adolimConfig'. Choices are: 'Config'.`
(can't run shell/dbshell eaither)

I tried to follow few potential solutions, like [this great one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408046/how-to-change-the-name-of-a-django-app) about how to update the app name, but anything I do lead me to that Error.

- also to change settings to: `adulim.apps.adulimConfig`

Any suggestions?   (not sure what to attach, added my settings)  Thanks.

**setting.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'home.apps.HomeConfig',
    'adolim.apps.adolimConfig',
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your INSTALLED_APPS setting simply to:

```
adulim.apps.Config
```

If that doesn't work, please post your `apps.py` file content which is needed to see what is missing or changed.