# I want the project to named something else. How can I safely rename the project?

Tags: python, django, rename

I have worked on my django project for quite a while, but realized I want the project to named something else.

How can I safely rename the project?

---

Edit:
[How to change the name of a Django app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408046/how-to-change-the-name-of-a-django-app) does not answer my question, as this question is to change the project name, not the app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the name of a Django app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408046/how-to-change-the-name-of-a-django-app)

Answer (score 1):

open your settings.py, urls.py, views.py or any other file that might rely on your project's name and then use the find&replace function in your text editor.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using refactor feature of the IDEs. If you are using pyCharm, go to refactor->rename. It will provide you an option to rename the references as well. Select that and IDE will take care of all you references without complications.