# virtualenv raises importerror because of changing app name in django

Tags: django, virtualenv, python-venv, django-apps

I've used [[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8408131/5968236)] to rename my django app. So I've edited some files and table's name and so on. But as it has been mentioned in that link, There is problem with virtualenv. So how can I fix it? I've change name "notes" to "blog".

[image]

The apps.py file:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
                                
class NotesConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'blog'
```

In the settings.py file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    // the rest installed apps
]
```

Comment: Can you please check your installed apps in settings.py file

Comment: Have you changed the app_label in the app config?
Please check this answer for details. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408046/how-to-change-the-name-of-a-django-app

Comment: @FaizP I've changed 'notes.apps.NotesConfig' to 'blog.apps.BlogConfig' in installed_apps part.

Comment: @DebashisDip Yes, as it was in the steps on that link, I've done that.

Comment: Can you post the `apps.py`?

Comment: @DebashisDip I've updated the question with the apps.py.

Comment: `blog.apps.BlogConfig` well  but you still have the class named as `NotesConfig` though, if you want to refer it that way, rename it too.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Yea right, I didn't see that old class name before! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say the name of this application is: *blog* and its following the normal folder structure django comes with.
so, the `settings.py` should be

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog',
]
```

and the `apps.py` should be

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig
                                
class BlogConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'blog'
```

Comment: Oops oh yeah! I didn't notice the old class name! Sorry and thank you!