# How to rename the folder of a Django model when there are external references to it?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

Recently I renamed a Django model and its parent folder:

from

```
input_source_type/
    models.py
```

to

```
event_source_type/
    models.py
```

The `models.py` contains the `InputSourceType` which is also renamed to `EventSourceType`.

Another model in (in the `system` folder) refers to to this model in its migration (0001_initial.py):

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('admin_input_source_type', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Systm',
            ...
```

When I run `python manage.py makemigrations` I got

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration admin_system.0001_initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('admin_input_source_type', '0001_initial')
```

which is correct as I don't the `admin_input_source_type` anymore.

I don't want to change the migration manually, what would be the Django way in this scenario?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you updated the name in the list of `installed_apps` in your `settings.py` file?

Comment: Hi @RifatRakib, yes, I did.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408046/how-to-change-the-name-of-a-django-app) should help, but I would recommend creating a new app to avoid many sensitive issues.