# Deploying python Django project to Heroku error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '<settings.py folder name>'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, heroku

Update: I made a breakthrough in understanding what my problem is, which I'll state below.

I am attempting to deploy a django project to Heroku and I'm stumped with this error right at the bottom:

```
2022-03-04T03:32:53.360457+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn --pythonpath backend.core backend.core.wsgi --log-file -`
2022-03-04T03:32:55.579764+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-03-04T03:32:54.908542+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-04 03:32:54 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2022-03-04T03:32:54.908855+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-04 03:32:54 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:39265 (4)
2022-03-04T03:32:54.908899+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-04 03:32:54 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2022-03-04T03:32:54.912389+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-04 03:32:54 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2022-03-04T03:32:54.974193+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-04 03:32:54 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113641+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-04 03:32:55 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113643+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113660+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113661+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113661+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113661+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113662+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113662+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113662+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113663+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113663+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113663+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113663+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113664+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113664+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113664+00:00 app[web.1]:     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113665+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113665+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113665+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113666+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113666+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113666+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113666+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113667+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113667+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/backend/core/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113667+00:00 app[web.1]:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113667+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113668+00:00 app[web.1]:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113668+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113668+00:00 app[web.1]:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113668+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 87, in __getattr__
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113668+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._setup(name)
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113669+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 74, in _setup
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113669+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113669+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 183, in __init__
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113669+00:00 app[web.1]:     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113670+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113670+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113670+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113670+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113671+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113671+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113671+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113671+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113671+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113671+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'
2022-03-04T03:32:55.113893+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-04 03:32:55 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2022-03-04T03:32:55.148185+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-04 03:32:55 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
```

In attempt to provide some information, inside my procfile

```
web: gunicorn --pythonpath backend.core backend.core.wsgi --log-file - 
release: python backend.manage.py makemigrations - - no-input
```

Inside requirements.txt

```
asgiref==3.5.0
attrs==21.4.0
beautifulsoup4==4.10.0
bs4==0.0.1
certifi==2021.10.8
charset-normalizer==2.0.12
Django==4.0.3
django-core==1.4.1
django-cors-headers==3.11.0
django-filter==21.1
djangorestframework==3.13.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna==3.3
jsonlines==3.0.0
lxml==4.8.0
pytz==2021.3
requests==2.27.1
soupsieve==2.3.1
sqlparse==0.4.2
urllib3==1.26.8
virtualenv-tools3==2.0.5
whitenoise==6.0.0
```

And I have my project set up as

`FE_APP/`

```
runtime.txt
requirements.txt
Procfile
backend/
scraper.py
```

Under `FE_APP/backend/`

```
api/
core/
static/
db.sqlite3
manage.py
```

and in `FE_APP/backend/core/`

```
__init__.py
errorlog
settings.py
urls.py
wsgi.py
```

In `FE_APP/backend/api/`, I have my `views.py` that does import from core.settings a couple variables.

`from core.settings import REALMS, GAME_TITLES`

But I doubt that's a concern for why this deployment is bugging out on me. I can deploy on my local machine just fine but heroku keeps giving me this error. I feel like I'm so close to deploying, what is going on?

---

March 7 update EDIT: I initially had the folder that contained settings.py and wsgi.py named 'core' and I recently changed it to 'feh' [following this tutorial here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408046/how-to-change-the-name-of-a-django-app). Now when I run the `heroku local` command on terminal, I get the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'feh'
```

Among other junk, leading me to believe there's no conflict between any django core module name conflicts with the folder. I don't know how to beat this, but I'm making progress at least.

Answer (score 1):

While I still haven't fully solved deployment as I still have another obstacle to figure out (which I will probably make another post for), I think I solved this one by adding to my wsgi.py file the whitenoise module and implementation below:

`wsgi.py`

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise import WhiteNoise

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'feh.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = WhiteNoise(application)
```

EDIT:
I also had another error that caused a heroku deployment failure where it could not find my manage.py file. this was caused by my Procfile not being set up properly,

`Procfile` needed to be set up as so.

```
web: gunicorn --pythonpath backend feh.wsgi --log-file - 
release: python backend/manage.py makemigrations --no-input
```

backend is the directory of the django project but it's not the root directory of project to be deployed, hence --pythonpath is needed to specify the django project directory. And I suppose the space in my --no-input flag also caused errors. [Thank you Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71387867/django-deployment-to-heroku-error-python-cant-open-file-app-backend-manage). After these and perhaps working some magic with gunicorn and whitenoise and the django-heroku modules (can't remember if this was before or after, sorry), I got it to work.