# django admin.autodiscover() import order on urls file

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-urls, pep8

I cloned a sample app for django and run code inspection and found that admin.autodiscover is called before importing the views file, that's used for the patterns later:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

admin.autodiscover()

import hello.views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", hello.views.index, name="index"),
    ...
]
```

This triggers a PEP8 code style warning as the imports are not all on the top of the file.
I'm afraid that moving it may have unintended side effects. Is that the case?

Comment: No, it won't have side effects. Moreover, it's [no longer necessary at all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12807691/3955830) since Django 1.8, so you can remove it completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#discovery-of-admin-files) you don't need to call the `autodiscover` function since django will call in when `AdminConfig` loads.