# Old version django on OpenShift

Tags: django, openshift

I need install old version Django on OpenShift. I change file setup.py and add 'django==1.5'. But after this change i don't may create superuser. 
When i changed setup.py and add 'Django==1.5', i get Internal Server Error 500. I looked logs - rhc tail MyApp.The logs is error - "ImproperlyConfigured: Middleware module "django.contrib.auth.middleware" does not define a "SessionAuthenticationMiddleware" class". If i head row 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware' in file settings.py when site working good, but i can't enter in admin panel on my site.

.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question with any errors you might be getting?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, sorry I  inattentive and stupid man. This answer for my issue - [Django. You don't have permission to edit anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718077/django-you-dont-have-permission-to-edit-anything).